# edit user profile image with usermanager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, edmx

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/259/asp-net-mvc-5-with-ef-6-working-with-files) to add profile picture once account create.

that edit has following snippet,

```
Student student = db.Students.Include(s => s.Files).SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
```

In above example it applied to table call `Student` in my case I want to go with `AspNetUser` table , but then I have to go with `UserManger` feature , Once I try to `Include` a file then it popping that error in compile time.

But in my scenario I'm trying to include in `AspNetUser` or `UserManager`

So to populate uploaded picture. I need `include` following code in user manager

```
var user = await UserManager.Include(s => s.Files).FindByIdAsync(userid);
```

but then getting following error

> 'ApplicationUserManager' does not contain a definition for 'Include'
>   and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ApplicationUserManager'

How to ignore and include files

**EDIT:**

These are the changes I've done in Model classes

**File**

```
public class File
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    ..

    public virtual ApplicationUser UserManager { get; set; }
}
```

**FilePath**

```
public class FilePath
{
    public int FilePathId { get; set; }
    ..

    public virtual ApplicationUser UserManager { get; set; }
}
```

**ApplicationUser**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
        ....

        public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

**AspNetUser**

```
public partial class AspNetUser
{

    public AspNetUser()
    {
       ..
    }
    ....

    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
}
```

---

then try to add migration to the project by typing the following into the PMC:

`add-migration File`

`add-migration FilePaths`

then getting following error in console

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly
>   'Project_Name'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations
>   command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations
>   configuration).

---

then I typed the following into the PMC:

`Enable-Migrations project_name.Models.sampleEntityFrameworkEntities`

then I got following error in console

> Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created
>   using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be
>   obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing
>   DbCompiledModel.

---

then I try to migrate `Files` and `FilesPath` using following code

`add-migration File`

`add-migration FilePaths`

Get error in console

> Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created
>   using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be
>   obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing
>   DbCompiledModel.

Comment: what type of **UserManager**?

Comment: Give a full description of the error

Comment: Actually in above example it applied to table call `Student` in my case I want to go with `AspNetUser` table , but then I have to go with UserManger feature , Once I try to `Include` it popping that error in compile time

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you're trying to follow the guide but using ASP.NET Identity. ASP.NET Identity is a unique system with its own classes and DBContext. In order to add new fields to the user you need to modify ApplicationUser class. Just add your property to this class and apply migration if needed. This will add a new column to the AspNetUser. Then add your field to the ViewModel (if any) and to other logic that is required to work with your field.

Comment: Actually I added following lines under `ApplicationUser` in `IdentityModel`  and `AspNetUser` model , `public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }` and `public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }` . then change line as above `var user = await UserManager.Include(s => s.Files).FindByIdAsync(userid);` but this also getting errors

Comment: Also I added following line in `File` and `FilePaths` classes `public virtual ApplicationUser UserManager { get; set; }` , then add a new migration to the project by typing the following into the PMC: `add-migration FilePaths` , then getting following error `No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Project_Name'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).`

Comment: Well, it is hard to say where  is the problem. Can you post all classes you are working on? I mean ApplicaitonUser, ApplicationDBContext and FilePath, and File. Not the whole code but part of every class